# No puedo ver las actions en Redux DevTools en React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

tengo un problema que no puedo visualizar mis actions en la extensión de Redux DevTools. La configuración que estoy usando es la siguiente:

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import userReducer from "./users/reducers/userReducer";

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
   user: userReducer,
  },
});

export default store;
```

```
   import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";

   import { Provider } from "react-redux";
   import store from "./app/store";

   import "./index.css";
   import App from "./App";

   const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));

   root.render(
     <Provider store={store}>
       <App />
     </Provider>
   );
```

Actualmente me muestra solo el estado inicial pero no se actualiza, no muestra las actions que deben seguir:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Use la documentación para guiarme en la configuración de la store. Alguna pista que estoy pasando por alto?

Answer (score 0):

es un problema comun, y para solucionarlo debes agregar la siguiente linea al store:
**window.**REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION** && window.**REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION**()**

```
const store = createStore( 
    reducers,
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
)
```